# Root access fail

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.10

I've installed next:

1. sudo apt-get install sendmail
2. sudo apt-get install telnetd

After sudo reboot and Can not login as root. 
I've tried to reset password from control panel, but it has no effect 
I can login as root only under another user using "su".\

It is virtual server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

add or uncomment this line
PermitRootLogin yes